# Testing Dynamic table RobotFrameowrok

Tags: robotframework

Load rows with tables into create list or what is better to use in this case? Then these selected specific rows click on button  I am a beginner. Thank You.

```
@{elements}=    Create List    xpath://td[text()="In Stock"]
:FOR
    ${element} IN   @{elements}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create list is a keyword from the BultIn library. This keyword will just create a list with the values that you are passing as an attribute. So basically what you are doing right there is to create a list with only one value  ('xpath://td[text()="In Stock"]')

You need to use the keyword **Get WebElements** this keyword will return a list of WebElement objects matching the locator.

```
@{elements}=    Get WebElements    xpath://td[text()="In Stock"]
:FOR
    ${element} IN   @{elements}
```

Answer (score 0):

please, in those values ​​that return web elements, browsing through the FOR variable {element} click on element type chcekbox

```
Click Element   ${element}     xpath://input[@type='checkbox']
```